# Cutting IP address and date and time

Tags: xml, bash

I have a log of security cameras.
I need only the IP addresses and date
How do I get out.

```
<Element>
<Section>Logon</Section>
<Section>admin</Section>
<Section>07/03/2016 21:55:50</Section>
<Section>125.035.058.002</Section>
</Element>

<Element>
<Section>Logoff</Section>
<Section>admin</Section>
<Section>07/03/2016 21:50:02</Section>
<Section>125.035.058.002</Section>
</Element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way with **`xmlstarlet`** tool:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//Section[position()=3 or position()=4]' -n input.xml
```

The output:

```
07/03/2016 21:55:50
125.035.058.002
07/03/2016 21:50:02
125.035.058.002
```

Comment: You makes assumptions on node order, not worth to explain it ? :)

Comment: @GillesQuenot, while requiring an explanation of someone's answer start with writing explanation on your own answer. Start from yourself. (P.S. I know the real motivation of your comment)

Comment: Can you elaborate ? Seems a bit aggressive at a first glance

Comment: @GillesQuenot, no aggression, just fairness

Comment: So no elaboration, dunno what you means by your comment

Comment: My answer don't makes assumtions on node order

Comment: @GillesQuenot, it doesn't matter (my answer is not your answer, my assumptions are not your assumptions)

Comment: Fair play is not your leitmotiv as I guess ^^

Comment: it's just your guessing, you may guess anything ... It won't make much sense for me

Answer (score 0):

The proper way (don't use awk, sed, regex etc...) using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) :

(assuming ip starts with 1 or 2)

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//Section[contains(text(), "/") or starts-with(text(), "1") or starts-with(text(), "2")]' file.xml
```

### Output :

```
07/03/2016 21:55:50
125.035.058.002
07/03/2016 21:50:02
125.035.058.002
```

Comment: The address has IP 0 before each octet. How do I erase it?

125.035.058.002

Comment: Don't understand your question

Comment: $ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//Section[contains(text(), "/") or starts-with(text(), "1") or starts-with(text(), "2")]' file.xml

Comment: Previous command
 xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//Section[contains(text(), "/") or starts-with(text(), "1") or starts-with(text(), "2")]' file.xml
Run before or after

Comment: `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//Section[contains(text(), "/") or starts-with(text(), "1") or starts-with(text(), "2")]' file.xml | sed -E 's/\.0+/./g'`